Why will data not save to SPDR over SPI in this code?
I am trying to learn SPI on an Arduino Uno (ATmega 328 MCU). I'm working in the Arduino IDE however I am programming in actual C, not the Arduino library. I have setup SPI functions from looking at some online examples. I'm not connected to anything, I'm just trying to verify that the functions work first on the master side. Doing some testing, it seems that the code is working up until the "SPDR = data" line.
void spi_init(void){
  DDRB |= (1 << MOSI_pin) | (1 << SCK_pin) | (1 << CS_pin) | (1 << RST_pin);
  PORTB |= (1 << CS_pin);
  SPCR = (1 << SPE) | (1 << MSTR) | (1 << SPR0);

  //LED ON 1
  PORTD |= (1 << LED_pin);
}

void spi_send(uint8_t data){
  SPDR = data;
  while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
}

void led(){

  spi_send(0xAA);

  //LED ON 2
  PORTD |= (1 << LED_pin);
  _delay_ms(2500);
  //LED OFF 2
  PORTD &= ~(1 << LED_pin);
  
  _delay_ms(2500);

  if(SPDR == 0xAA){
    //LED ON 3
    PORTD |= (1 << LED_pin);
  }
}

I have tried to test the code by blinking an LED when I initialize SPI, then again when spi_send() is called, and then again after the SPDR = data line. Additionally, I have used the Arduino library's Serial.print() function to print SPDR to the serial monitor in hex. When I do this, it is just printing 0 even though it should be printing 0xFF. Again, I just want to verify that I have the setup things working correctly before I proceed to testing a connection between a master and slave.

"I'm not connected to anything", why are you expecting to receive anything with if(SPDR == 0xAA) or 0xFF? SPI send out a byte via MOSI and at the same time received one byte from MISO.  See figure 1 of SPI wikipedia.

Check the level on pin MISO, and [edit] your question to explain why you expect to receive 0xFF.

If MISO is pulled low it will produce 0x00, if it is pulled high 0xFF, if it is floating, it could anything, but 0x00 is plausible.  Why do you expect 0xFF?  If you want to test without a device, pull it high and test, then pull it low and test, then loop back MOSI to MISO, and test.

The data is shifted out of SPDR.  You have a line right after waiting for the SPIF flag.  On e that flag is set all the data in SPDR is sent and now SPDR contained the data received back.  But since you don't have anything connected, nothing but zeroes were received and that's what you read.

It depends on the level at pin MISO, for example with a pull-up it will be 0xFF. That's why I asked about that.

Using a chip that does not utilize MISO. Master only writes to it so no signal to be returned. No voltage is being output (it is a DAC) and barely any votlage (~9mV) being read on the SPI connection pins

So there's no miso and no signal to the miso pin on Arduino.  But the Arduino board can't tell the difference between that and something that is connected and sending zeroes.  Either way, the point is that after you send your data it won't be there in SPDR anymore.  You shouldn't expect to find it still there.
